# Do we need both the [comparative-linguistics] and [typology] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As of right now, we have both the [typology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typology) and [comparative-linguistics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-linguistics) tags. Currently [typology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typology) lacks usage recommendations, which I think we see reflected in the questions that have been tagged with it. The [comparative-linguistics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-linguistics) tag does have usage recommendations, which describe the tag as being for "questions about the similarities and/or differences between two conlangs or a conlang and a natlang." However, what this describes is usually considered a subset of linguistic typology, which is concerned with classifying languages based on their features and with describing common structural and featural properties of language and their distribution throughout the world's languages.

Based on this, is it necessary to have both of these tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these tags should be merged into a single tag and that [typology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typology) should be the master tag, since the way these tags have been used on this site, which has so far been to compare languages with similar features or to discuss feature-based classifications like "analytic" and "synthetic", is pretty much exactly what would be described as "linguistic typology."

Linguists typically use "comparative linguistics" to describe the subfield of historical linguistics that evaluates the relatedness of languages using the comparative method, referring more to the genetic relatedness of two languages rather than possession of similar features. Comparative linguistics under this definition isn't really particularly relevant to conlanging, so I don't think having [comparative-linguistics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-linguistics) as a tag synonym for [typology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typology) is a bad thing, but because "typology" is more technically accurate I believe it should be the master tag.

Comment: I think I agree, but three of the comparative-linguistics tagged questions are about general comparisons that wouldn't really be appropriately tagged as typology.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't think general comparisons of languages (I assume you mean the "how similar is X to Y" questions) fall outside the scope of typology, actually. They might not be the kinds of typological questions a linguist might ask, but they're certainly more typological than they are any other linguistic subfield. In any case, I don't think it would be a problem to have such questions tagged under the typology master tag -- we can afford for the tag to be a bit broader, I think.

Comment: Time to move this forward probably. Any ideas of a good tag description?

Comment: @curiousdannii Something like "Questions about comparing languages or classifying them into categories based on their linguistic features", perhaps? I'm open to suggestions for improvements, though.

Comment: @curiousdannii This is one that would probably need to have a proper tag wiki, tbh.